# GCP load balancer stuck in FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am trying to create a load balancer using a app engine backend. I followed [the official guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#console) . I followed [this (pretty good) tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qXM7kHlk1U) too. I can't get the domain status to switch to ACTIVE. It remains stuck as FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE, which indicates there may be a problem with setting the domain names.

I don't know what's missing. I have a relatively simple LB setting. The frontend is defined with the HTTPS protocol and an ephemeral address (*@frontend_ip*).

In the Cloud DNS, I created a zone with the following record sets :

- / A record type / IPv4 = *@frontend_ip*
- www / CNAME record type / IPv4 = *@frontend_ip*

The SSL certificate has the 2 same domain names defined as above (with and without www). I selected the Google managed certificate type.

The following command `gcloud compute target-https-proxies list` shows my target-proxy is associated with my SSL certificate.

I tried a different way by creating an External IP address first, as explained in the above linked guide. Then, by selecting this External IP address in my Frontend configuration, instead of an ephemeral address. Then by selecting this External IP address as the IPv4 address of my domain names definitions. That doesn't seem to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I don't know what's missing. I've tried to delete it all and re create the LB and DNS settings.

Comment: You state that you created a **zone**. Is that zone pointed to by your domain registrar? Your problem is most likely incorrect DNS setup. Start at your Domain Registrar and make sure everything is set up correctly. Since you created a new zone, you probably have a Name Server problem.

Comment: ok, I got it. It works now. I was initially trying to configure a load balancer with the default firebase domain names (mysite.web.app), for testing purposes. I guess that is not possible to do. That's what confused me. It's only possible with a custom domain name it seems.

Comment: It is only possible with a domain you **control**. The domain **web.app** is owned/controlled by Google.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you created a zone. Is that zone pointed to by your domain registrar? Your problem is most likely incorrect DNS setup. Start at your Domain Registrar and make sure everything is set up correctly. Since you created a new zone, you probably have a Name Server problem